# 2D Array fails to shift

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array

I am developing an arcade game. I have a 2D array which I use to draw a tile based map. I shift the array because when player move map/level should shift to right.

To do this I copy a portion of the whole map to the current map which is on the screen and update the portion.

This code runs correctly only in the first run then does nothing when it is called.

```
public void shiftMap(){
    //tMap is the tile map
    for(int i = 0; i < tMap.getCurrentRows(); i++){
        for (int j = 0; j < tMap.getCurrentCols(); j++) {
        //getMap returns the whole map and getCurrentMap returns the portion
            tMap.getCurrentMap()[i][j] = tMap.getMap()[i][j+1];
        }
    }
}
```

Any ideas why I fail? Thanks.

Comment: Yes, it returns correct values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you problem would be that you always start from 0. I would think you need to start from the current coordinates.
Something like

```
public void shiftMap(){
    for(int i = tMap.getCurrentX(); i < tMap.getCurrentRows(); i++){
        for (int j = tMap.getCurrentY(); j < tMap.getCurrentCols(); j++) {
            tMap.getCurrentMap()[i][j] = tMap.getMap()[i][j+1];
        }
    }
}
```

Where getCurrentX() & getCurrentY() would return the base coordinates that you need to start rendering from.

Comment: Thanks for the help.